# No Node Available Exception in Elastic Search

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I am very new to elastic search concepts. I am trying to build a simple application using elastic search.

```
public class App 
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    try {
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

        ElasticOperations.addDocToIndex(client, ElasticUtility.getJsonMap("Sandesha", "male", "jsandesh08@gmail.com", "Hassan"));
        System.out.println("Doc added");
        client.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

But, When tried to run this program, I am getting `NoNodeAvailableException`.

> Exception in thread "main" NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{w1bSLAN-TFWUHE1PA3qDeQ}{localhost}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:347)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:245)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:363)
>       at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:408)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:80)
>       at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:54)
>       at com.sandesha.elasticsearch.Elastic.ElasticOperations.addDocToIndex(ElasticOperations.java:11)
>       at com.sandesha.elasticsearch.Elastic.App.main(App.java:27)

Please help me resolve this issue.
My `ElasticOperations` class is,

```
public class ElasticOperations {

public static void addDocToIndex(TransportClient client, Map<String,Object> jsonMap)
{
    client.prepareIndex("customers", "personal").setSource(jsonMap).execute().actionGet();
}

}
```

And my `ElasticUtility` class looks like,

```
public class ElasticUtility {

public static Map<String, Object> getJsonMap(String name, String gender, String email, String city)
{
    Map<String,Object> jsonMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    jsonMap.put("name", name);
    jsonMap.put("gender", gender);
    jsonMap.put("email", email);
    jsonMap.put("city", city);

    return jsonMap;
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you connect to the elastic from terminal or using sense ?

Comment: I can connect through terminal. It runs on the port 9200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a cluster name mismatch. If your cluster name is not "elasticsearch" that's likely the problem.

Go to http://localhost:9200 in a browser and grab your cluster name.  Then, try adding the cluster name property to the TransportClient as follows:

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                            .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch_foo").build();
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                         .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
```

Comment: fabulous, thank you. Note also that you can issue a get /nodes call to find out the cluster name